# I am getting a compile error, integer expression must be constant. Why am I getting it and how would I fix it?

Tags: integer, constants

Somewhat new to coding, trying to get LEDS to light up using an array. All ready my first 2 lines of code are not working. When compiling it says the integer expression must be constant? Can anyone explain why and how I can fix it?

```
const int size = 8;

int led[size] = {BIT0, BIT1, BIT2, BIT3, BIT4, BIT5, BIT6, BIT7};
```

Comment: Please indicate what language this is. Looks like C? Its helpful to add a tag indicating the language.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is C++

Comment: How are BIT0, BIT1, etc. defined? If I used your code and replace BIT0, BIT1, etc. with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 this code compiles just fine using VS 2017. What compiler are you using?